# Instance method nearly matches optional Requirement

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, swift-protocols, socketrocket

I have a class in swift which implements `SRWebSocketDelegate` protocol written in objective-c. When I try to implement it's optional method `webSocketDidOpen`, then I get the following warning:
[image]

Also, when I run my code the implementation for webSocketDidOpen is not getting called and the code directly goes to `webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket, didReceiveMessageWith string: String)`

How do I implement the optional methods of my protocol written in Objective-C and also get rid of these warnings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you choose the “Rename” fix-it?

Comment: @robmayoff, Wouldn't that make it as an local instance method instead of implemented method of SRWebSocketDelegate?

Comment: It already isn't the protocol implementation; that's what the warning is telling you. The fixit is trying to make it match the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SRWebSocket.h` is annotated `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`, so by default all values are `nonnull`. That means that this:

```
- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
```

Is imported as:

```
func webSocketDidOpen(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket)
```

But you implemented:

```
func webSocketDidOpen(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!)
```

`SRWebSocket` is not the same type as `SRWebSocket!`. Remove the `!`. This is likely what the rename fixit will do for you.

Comment: Didn't realise it was such a small issue. Thanks!

Comment: If Rob solved your problem, please click the check mark next to his answer.